# Как вывести из списка чётное число, если все остальные значения будут нечётные, и наоборот?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Списков могут быть два вида, со всеми чётными числами и одним нечётным, и со всеми нечётными числами и одним чётным. В списке может быть минимум три значения.

Списки для примера:

```
[2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36] # должно вывести 11 (как одно нечетное)
[160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21] # должно вывести 160 (как одно четное)
```

Как написать код, чтобы выводилось именно одно отличающееся число?

Comment: что выводить из списка [1, 2]? или (не)четных всегда больше одного и заранее известно, чего больше в списке?

Comment: Мне кажется, мог бы выйти неплохой code golf

Comment: В первом списке все четные кроме 11, его надо вывести, во втором все нечетные кроме 160, это число и нужно выводить. Понятно объяснил?

Comment: @Freerade вас спросили, какое число выводить, если список будет [1, 2]. Понятно объяснил? или в третий раз кто-то должен спросить?

Comment: Нет, такого не будет, список либо со всеми четными числами и одним нечетным, либо со всеми нечетными и одним четным. Списков [1,2,3,6] не будет.

Comment: @Freerade Cписок [1, 2] является списком со всеми четными числами и одним нечетным. Он же является списком со всеми нечетными и одним четным.

Comment: 3 значения минимум.

Comment: Алсо, спасибо оба варианта рабочии.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например так (при условии, что есть 3 элемента, иначе нельзя определить, чего больше):

```
res = [max, min][sum(x % 2 for x in l[:3]) > 1](l, key=lambda x: x % 2)
```

Answer (score 6):

Если отличный (по четности) элемент **всегда один**, можно так:

```
odd = [x for x in my_list if x%2]
even = [x for x in my_list if not x%2]

if len(odd) == 1:
    print(*odd)
else:
    print(*even)
```

при

```
my_list = [2, 4, 0, 100, 4, 11, 2602, 36]
```

выведет 11, а для

```
my_list = [160, 3, 1719, 19, 11, 13, -21]
```

выведет, соответственно, 160

Comment: если [1,2], то преимущество отдается нечетному.

Comment: Ну все работает, только непонятно почему кодвар у меня не принимает ваш вариант, я просто запихнул его в функцию

Comment: Там два ретерна вместо принтов, в компиляторе при этом все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант, не проходит по всему списку. Как только встречен нужный элемент, обход прекращается:

```py
def one_parity_element(x):
    parity = sum(i & 1 for i in x[:3]) < 2
    return next(filter(lambda i: i & 1 == parity, x))
```